# How to keep one image button active until another is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, button, onclick, mouseover

I'm setting up a website using  (div may be a better choice but at the moment i'm using frame). It is made up of menu.html & main.html. Main.html changes respectively to which button is clicked in the menu.html.

menu.html
- approximately 9 buttons
- each button has 3 relevant images
  - default (xxx.jpg)
  - on mouseover (xxx_hover.jpg)
  - on click (xxx_onclick.jpg)

AIM
1. image changes on mouseover and return to default on mouseout
2. image changes on click, and remains clicked until another is clicked (within the same frame)

what I have so far...
I am not sure how to keep the image stay as xxx_onclick.jpg until another is click. Also, with the below code, I get an error; when I mouseover on an image that is clicked, it will try to find xxx_onclick_hover.jpg which doesn't exist. I am uncertain what function(s) I should be using.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<img class="menu_btn" src="button1S.jpg"><br>
<img class="menu_btn" src="button2S.jpg"><br>
<img class="menu_btn" src="button3S.jpg"><br>
<img class="menu_btn" src="button4S.jpg">
</body>

<script>
$(".menu_btn")
    .mouseover(function() {//onmouseover
    this.src = this.src.replace('.jpg', '_hover.jpg');//replace src link from .jpg to _hover.jpg
    })

    .mouseout(function() {//onmouseout
    this.src = this.src.replace('_hover.jpg', '.jpg');//replace src link from _hover.jpg to .jpg
    })

    .click(function() {//onclick
    $(".menu_btn").unbind('mouseover');//disable mouseover to prevent error (ie. button1S_onclick_hover.jpg), but this disable all images...
    this.src = this.src.replace('_hover.jpg', '_onclick.jpg');//onclick reply _hover.jpg to _onclick.jpg
    }
);
</script>
```

Thank you very much in advance.

below is a set of code tested with Joce's suggestion
*not 100% functional yet.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .menu-btn {
            background: url('http://icdn.pro/images/en/s/m/smiley-smile-icone-8052-128.png') no-repeat center;
            width: 128px;
            height: 128px;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .menu-btn:hover {
            background: url('http://www.baza-lesnik.ru/images/blobwars.png') no-repeat center;
        }
        .menu-btn.active {
            background: url('http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/40230.png') no-repeat center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#" class="menu-btn"></a>
    <a href="#" class="menu-btn"></a>
    <a href="#" class="menu-btn"></a>
    <a href="#" class="menu-btn"></a>
    <a href="#" class="menu-btn"></a>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".menu-btn").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".menu-btn.active").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");

            //Do more things
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of changing the image source directly in your Javascript, change the class of the `img` element and have the desired images assigned to each class.

Comment: Patrick, thanks for the advice. I believe your suggestion is what Joce answered with. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use `a` instead of `img` and set the `background-image`.
On click, remove the CSS class `active` and add it to the clicked button.

Here is the code:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .menu-btn {
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .menu-btn-1 {
            background: url('xxx.jpg') no-repeat center;
        }

        .menu-btn-1:hover {
            background: url('xxx_hover.jpg') no-repeat center;
        }
        .menu-btn-1.active {
            background: url('xxx_onClick.jpg') no-repeat center;
        }

        .menu-btn-2 {
            background: url('xxx.jpg') no-repeat center;
        }

        .menu-btn-2:hover {
            background: url('xxx_hover.jpg') no-repeat center;
        }
        .menu-btn-2.active {
            background: url('xxx_onClick.jpg') no-repeat center;
        }

        ...
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#" class="menu-btn menu-button-1"></a>
    <a href="#" class="menu-btn menu-button-2"></a>
    <a href="#" class="menu-btn menu-button-3"></a>
    <a href="#" class="menu-btn menu-button-4"></a>
    <a href="#" class="menu-btn menu-button-5"></a>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".menu-btn").on("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".menu-btn.active").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");

            //Do more things
        });
    });
</script>
```

***Edit:***

Since you have a different image for each button, you should add a class to handle the `background-image`. I edited the code above.

If you prefer to use javascript instead, you could listen to the `mouseover` and `click` events and change the `background-image` in jQuery.

Comment: Joce, thank you very much for your solution. I will give it a test. I have a question for this method. Given that I have 9 buttons, does it mean I will have to make 9 css and 9 class? I am trying to keep it simple, it would help with less codes or class.

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to tag it as answer if it solve your problem!

To answer your question, a CSS class can be used as many as you want on multiple HTML tags. A class define the style for the element, so you don't need to make 9 class, you only need one and add the class on each element that you want to apply the style.

Comment: Joce, I have just gave it a try. The hover works fine, but onclick doesn't react. Am I missing something? By the way, since for all the <a> the class is the same, the all hold the same image...I have 9 buttons with a different image for each....guess I have to use like...class="menu-btn", class="menu-btn2" ?

Comment: Could you edit your first post with the new code that you just tried?